# No module named 'jax.experimental.global_device_array' when running the official Flax Example on Colab with V100

Tags: jax, flax

I have been trying to understand [this official flax example](https://github.com/google/flax/tree/main/examples/imagenet/), based on a Coalb pro+ account with V100. When I execute the command `python main.py --workdir=./imagenet --config=configs/v100_x8.py` , the returned error is

```
File "/content/FlaxImageNet/main.py", line 29, in <module>
import train
File "/content/FlaxImageNet/train.py", line 30, in <module>
from flax.training import checkpoints
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/flax/training/checkpoints.py", line 34, 
in <module>
from jax.experimental.global_device_array import GlobalDeviceArray
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'jax.experimental.global_device_array'
```

I am not sure whether global_device_array has been moved from `jax.experimental` package or it is no longer needed or replaced by other equivalent methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GlobalDeviceArray` was [deprecated in JAX version 0.4.1](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/changelog.html#jax-0-4-1-dec-13-2022) and [removed in JAX version 0.4.7](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/changelog.html#jax-0-4-7-march-27-2023).

With that in mind, it seems the code in question requires JAX version 0.4.6 or older. You might consider reporting this incompatibility to the flax project: http://github.com/google/flax/.

Comment: Hi! Then is there a way to run the `main.py` by changing it to some similar functionality? Also I will report this~ Thank you very much.

Comment: I'm also facing the same problem, what would be the replacement for GlobalDeviceArray? Thanks @jakevdp

Comment: It depends on the context, but you should generally use `jax.Array`.